# Julia PyCall Bokeh in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, julia, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

Using Julia's PyCall to call Python's Bokeh running in a Jupyter notebook:

```
using PyCall

@pyimport numpy as np
@pyimport bokeh.plotting as plotting
@pyimport bokeh.io as io

io.output_notebook()

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,box_select"

p1 = plotting.figure(title="Legend Example", tools=TOOLS)
p1[:circle](x,   y, legend="sin(x)")

io.show(p1)
```

Instead of getting a plot like in the Bokeh [examples](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyter-interactors) I get:

```
Out[1]: <Bokeh Notebook handle>
```

- Works fine in a Python 2/3 notebook.
- Using `Docker/datascience-notebook` base image.

Comment: You probably need to define a mime type for it to display in the notebook. I would check how PyPlot sets its display/show functions.

Comment: Could it be related to this warning: `WARNING: Base.writemime is deprecated.
  likely near /home/jovyan/.julia/v0.5/IJulia/src/kernel.jl:31`

Comment: As a complete aside, I would very much like to help someone take over and maintain Bokeh.jl (native Julia bindings for Bokeh). If you or anyone you know might be interested please have them contact me or the main project mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh

Comment: Have you opened an issue on the Bokeh.jl repo?

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders This is not a Bokeh.jl issue.  I would ask for help there but project seems to be dead.